# How to get the percentage of memory free with a Linux command?

Tags: linux, memory

I would like to get the available memory reported as a percentage using a Linux command line.

I used the `free` command, but that is only giving me numbers, and there is no option for percentage.

Answer (score 178, accepted):

Using the `free` command:

```
% free
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       2061712     490924    1570788          0      60984     220236
-/+ buffers/cache:     209704    1852008
Swap:       587768          0     587768
```

Based on this output we grab the line with `Mem` and using awk pick specific fields for our computations.

This will report the percentage of memory in use

```
% free | grep Mem | awk '{print $3/$2 * 100.0}'
23.8171
```

This will report the percentage of memory that's free

```
% free | grep Mem | awk '{print $4/$2 * 100.0}'
76.5013
```

You could create an alias for this command or put this into a tiny shell script. The specific output could be tailored to your needs using formatting commands for the print statement along these lines:

```
free | grep Mem | awk '{ printf("free: %.4f %\n", $4/$2 * 100.0) }'
```

Comment: `free -t | grep "buffers/cache" | awk '{print $4/($3+$4) * 100}'` also works quite well as it reports numbers that match Mem in htop/top

Comment: @KevinJalbert's : works wonderfully, thank you. We can however omit the `grep` & go straight to `awk`: `free | awk '/buffers\/cache/{print $4/($3+$4) * 100.0;}'`

Comment: @Wrikken : also works wonderfully, thank you. But we can enhance it by dropping in the other figures as percentages too `free | awk '/Mem/{printf("used: %.2f%"), $3/$2*100} /buffers\/cache/{printf(", buffers: %.2f%"), $4/($3+$4)*100} /Swap/{printf(", swap: %.2f%"), $3/$2*100}'`

Comment: I'm using free for SWAP, and sometimes SWAP is zero. So I get a division by zero error. Anyway of just making it 0 if it's divided by 0?

Comment: Putting some lipstick on it: `alias memuse='free | awk '"'"'/Mem/{printf "Mem used: %.0f% \nMem free: %.0f%\n", $3/$2*100, $4/$2*100}'"'"`

Comment: This doesn't seem very portable. On arch, when running `free -m`, I don't have the third line "-/+ buffers/cache:"

Comment: `free | awk '/Mem/{printf("Mem used: %.1f%"), $3/($2+.000000001)*100} /buffers\/cache/{printf(", buffers: %.1f%"), $4/($3+$4)+.000000001*100} /Swap/{printf(", swap: %.1f%"), $3/($2+.000000001)*100}';` without division by zero

Comment: `awk '$1=="MemTotal:" {t=$2}; $1=="MemAvailable:" {a=$2; print 100*(t-a)/t; exit}' /proc/meminfo`

Comment: This command fails if the system language is not English.

Comment: This does not appear to be portable - I get a completely different result structure for the `free` command on Mint

Comment: **For all lines (Mem, Swap and Total)** us this `free -t | tail -n+2 | awk '{($2>0) ? p=$3/$2*100.0 : p=0.0; print "Used " $1 "\t" p "%"}'`. It also prevents the `division by zero` error when swap is 0