# Determine 'Free' Memory in Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, memory-management

I'm wondering if there is an easy way to determine the amount of "utilized" memory in Linux. Specifically, memory that is actively in use by the Kernel and applications and not counting the buffers and cached memory. I'm looking for something analogous to Window's reporting of used memory found in the task manager (Where you see the percentage of memory used).

So far, the closest solution I can think of to calculate it comes from this link: [Determining Free Memory on Linux](http://blog.scoutapp.com/articles/2010/10/06/determining-free-memory-on-linux)

On my Ubuntu 13.0.4, doing a `cat /proc/meminfo`, 
I then calculate `100-(((MemFree+Buffers+Cached)/MemTotal)*100)` which should give the percentage of "utilized" memory.

This is the closest way I found to get a Physical Memory percentage like the one found in window's task manager.

Does this seem like a valid approach? And if so, are there more straight-forward approaches?

Comment: yes, parse /proc/meminfo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use AWK to parse the output of the free command, and get a percentage.

`free | grep Mem | awk '{print $4/$2 * 100}'`

[Linux command for percentage of memory that is free](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585978/linux-command-for-percentage-of-memory-that-is-free)

Comment: This is very close to what I want, I just modified it to get cached and buffers which I consider 'free' memory as well. `free | grep Mem | awk '{print 100-(($4+$6+$7)/$2 * 100)}'`  I'm able to get percentage of memory used. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I am a fan of `free -m`

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          1446       1172        273          0        225        821
-/+ buffers/cache:        126       1320
Swap:         1471          0       1471
```

Comment: I generally also add the `-t` option, and on some larger systems I use `-g` instead of `-m`, but that's the cool thing - it's flexible...

Comment: In case you (like me) were wondering what those do, -t shows the total for RAM and swap. -m and -g are megabytes and gigabytes, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

This show you memory stats in a more human readable way:

```
sar -r 0
```