# How to calculate half of total memory rounded up to next 1G boundary?

Tags: bash, awk

How can I extend the answer in [Linux command for percentage of memory that is free](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585978/linux-command-for-percentage-of-memory-that-is-free) so I can get the total memory in rounded up to the next 1G boundary? For example,

```
# free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7.4G        2.0G        3.0G        150M        2.4G        5.0G
Swap:            0B          0B          0B
```

I want the value of "free -h | awk {...}" to be 4, since total Mem = 7.4G, so 7.4/2 = 3 + 1 = 4. Make sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming everything in G, you need:

```
free -h | awk 'NR==2{print(int(substr($2,1,length($2)-1)/2+.5))}'
```

---

**Explanation:**

To print the second line, you need

```
free -h | awk 'NR==2{print}'
```

To print the second field of the second line, you need

```
free -h | awk 'NR==2{print($2)}' # prints 7.7G
```

To remove the final G, you need substring which start at 1st character and contains as many character as in the string, minus 1.

```
free -h | awk 'NR==2{print(substr($2,1,length($2)-1))}' # prints 7.7
```

To get half of it, you need

```
free -h | awk 'NR==2{print(substr($2,1,length($2)-1)/2)}' # prints 3.85
```

To round to the closest integer, you need to add 0.5 and truncate the fractional part (which is done by `int` function)

```
free -h | awk 'NR==2{print(int(substr($2,1,length($2)-1)/2+.5))}' # prints 4
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for my case, where everything is indeed in "G". Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
awk '$1=="MemTotal:"{t=$2}END{printf("%.0f GB\n", t/2/1024/1024)}' /proc/meminfo
```

Comment: Are you sure it isn't t/2/1024/1024 ? Is 1GB=1024000KB ? Seems improbable.  (Hard disk manufacturers sometimes cheat like this, but we are talking about RAM.)

Comment: This printed out "8 GB" instead of just "8". Removing the GB in the print statement worked though.