# Show ram usage percent in command prompt

Tags: memory, command-prompt

I know this is probably a noob question but I'm trying to write a script that needs to obtain the system ram usage in a percent and output it like this `5%` but I cant find any resources on how to do that. If anyone could help I would appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: Which OS is this on?

Comment: If it's for Linux there a dup here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585978/linux-command-for-percentage-of-memory-that-is-free

Comment: Do You like to do free -h?