# Bash: Is there a more efficient way of getting RAM used in percentage by /proc/meminfo

Tags: bash, performance, statusbar, code-cleanup

This is the code I made, it does work, but I know is bad and not really efficient

```
#!/urs/bin/bash
ramav="$(($(grep -m1 'MemAvailable:' /proc/meminfo | awk '{print $2}') / 1024))"
ramtotal="$(($(grep -m1 'MemTotal:' /proc/meminfo | awk '{print $2}') / 1024))"
ramuse="$(($ramtotal-$ramav))"
ram1="$(($ramtotal / 100))"
echo  %"$(($ramuse/$ram1))"
```

*I'm learning bash scripting, for practice i'm ricing my DWM's status bar as a way to learn, my problem here is that I don't really know all the commands that could help this run better, I will really appreciate the help and I'm willing to learn, that's the whole point of what I'm doing these. Thanks for your time! and happy new year.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the percentage of memory free with a Linux command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585978/how-to-get-the-percentage-of-memory-free-with-a-linux-command)

Comment: If you were going to script this by reading from /proc/meminfo, you'd be much better doing the whole thing in `awk`. It can do searching (removing the need for `grep`), and it can do math (floating point, unlike bash!). Try this: `awk '$1=="MemAvailable:" {ramav=$2}; $1=="MemTotal:" {ramtotal=$2}; END {print 100*(ramtotal-ramav)/ramtotal}' /proc/meminfo`

Comment: @GordonDavisson Thanks man your great!, is there a way in bash to round the out put?

Comment: Again, it's easier in `awk`, using `printf` instead of `print`: `{printf "%i\n", 100*(ramtotal-ramav)/ramtotal}` to get it as an integer. Or, you could replace the `%i` with `%.1f` to print one digit after the decimal print, `%.2f` for two digits, etc.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Thanks man, this has helped me a lot, Thanks for the answer and everything, I really appreciate it